# Potentials that prevent the phase flow of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, phase-space, complex-systems

I am trying to solve a question that my professor gave.

> When a particle moves in one dimension $x$ in a potential $U(x)$ , the resulting motion over a very short time interval is specified by Newton’s equation, provided $x(0)$ and $\dot x(0)$ are given.
> Often the resulting motion can be determined over an arbitrarily long time. The resulting
> motion in phase space is called the phase flow. But for some potentials the motion can’t be
> determined arbitrarily long times: there is no phase flow. If $U(x)$ has the form ($-Cx^n$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant), there are some values of the positive integer $n$ for which
> the motion doesn’t define a phase flow. What are these values and what prevents the system
> from having a phase flow?
>
> Hint: From the conservation of energy trying to get $x(t)$ for all $t$ and see for what values of $n$ you
> get into trouble.

Could anyone please give some other hints to do this problem

Comment: The problem is in the possible blow up of solutions in finite time. Check out the case $U = -x^4$ for example.

Comment: What do you mean by blowup of solutions @lpz

Comment: Solutions go to $\pm\infty$ in finite time

Comment: Is it in general n>2 doesn't have a phase flow@lpz

Comment: Depends on the sign of $C$